# How do I tell my rails form to use https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I have a rails app and on this particular page (uses SSL) I have a form for created 'posts' and then separate form used for uploading images that belong to the post.

The image form is:

```
<%= form_for Image.new, :html => {:multipart => true} do |g| %>
<%= g.text_field :whence, :id => "postWhence"%>
<%= g.file_field :image, :id => "postImage_file_field", multiple: true, name: "image[image]" %>
<%= g.file_field :image, :id =>"postLogo_file_field"%>
<% end %>
```

I've seen people add `:secure => true` and `:protocol => 'https'`, but that only seems to fit in if the format of the form for is something like 
`form_for @user, :url => user_path(:secure => true)`.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because when I deployed to my production server, image uploading suddenly did not work, and when checking the log I saw:

```
Filter chain halted as :ensure_proper_protocol rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)" when I attempted to upload the image.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just override the url as you alluded to. Something like:

```
<%= form_for Image.new, :url => image_path(:protocol => 'https'), :html => {:multipart => true} do |g| %>
```

Here are the docs on using `url_for`. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for

The `url` option in `form_for` takes the same fields you pass to `url_for` or `link_to`.

Comment: Using image_path gave me a routing error, 'No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"images"}'.

Comment: When does the error happen, on the page load or when you submit the form? You also have to have the correct routes and controller actions set up. If you post them I will take a look.